# C++ Структура. use of deleted function operator=

Tags: c++, функции, struct

```
// menu.h

struct MenuParameter {
   String textBefore;
   unsigned int &value;
   String (&valueFormatter)(unsigned int value);
   String textAfter;
};


// menu.cpp


void MenuParameterController::add(
   String textBefore,
   unsigned int &value,
   String (&valueFormatter)(unsigned int value),
   String textAfter
) {
  items[itemsCount] = {textBefore, value, valueFormatter, textAfter};
}
```

Лог компилятора

> use of deleted function 'MenuParameter& MenuParameter::operator=(MenuParameter&&)'
>
> 'MenuParameter& MenuParameter::operator=(MenuParameter&&)' is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
> struct MenuParameter {

Почему это возникает и как избежать?

Comment: *"'MenuParameter& MenuParameter::operator=(MenuParameter&&)' is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed"*

Comment: Это русский раздел SO, тут задают вопросы на русском. Пожалуйста, переведите его на русский язык или удалите.

Comment: This is Russian section of stackoverflow. Here you can ask only in Russian. So please translate your question or [ask on English stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 2):

Причина состоит в том, что структура имеет в качестве члена данных объект ссылочного типа

```
unsigned int &value;
```

Объекты ссылочного типа должны инициализироваться при создании объекта класса или структуры. Вы не можете переназначить ссылку. Поэтому неявный копирующий оператор присваивания объявляется компилятором как удаленный.

Из стандарта C++ (12.8 Copying and moving class object)

> 23 A defaulted copy/move assignment operator for class X **is deﬁned
>   as deleted** if X has:
>
> ...
>
> - a non-static data member of **reference type**, or

Вам следует в явном виде определить копирующий оператор присваивания, если это возможно.

В вашем случае вы могли бы вместо ссылки объявить указатель. Например,

```
struct MenuParameter {
   String textBefore;
   unsigned int *value;
                ^^^^^^ 
   String (&valueFormatter)(unsigned int value);
   String textAfter;
};
```

и соответствующим образом определить копирующий оператор присваивания.

Comment: А почему такой вариант прокатывает при обьявлении структуры как типа и самой переменной в одном файле?

Comment: @el-fuego  Объявить структуру ничто не мешает. Члены данных класса могут быть ссылками. Другое дело, что если объявляется переменная такого типа, и объект типа ссылки при этом не инициализируется, то такая программа называется ill-formed, то есть некорректная.